# Spring data jpa populate data relationships

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, repository, spring-data-jpa

I use the spring data jpa framework to easily handle the whole dao stuff and it is awesome. A couple of days ago I test the repo populator functionality of spring data jpa and it also worked pretty smooth, but is it possible to handle relationships ? not the cascade persist types, they are easy to handle ... I mean those one to one relationships where the data for this type is provides by another json file.

Hmm I hope it is a bit understandable what I want to do. Did anyone has an idea to handle this with spring data jpa?

Thanks for any kind of help and have a good weekend :)

Comment: let me know if you find an answer

Comment: Spring Data does offer `@OneToOne` `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations, do you know if these are what you need? Would you like me to elaborate?

Comment: @SamanthaCatania did you mean that spring data it self provides the relationship annotations? I only know the ones from jpa.

Comment: The java persistance annotations are supported by spring data

Comment: Yeah that is right, but it is not noted by the repository populators. I ran in the same issue a couple of weeks ago and boostraped my a bit more complex domain with a custom boostrap mechanism.